# Navicat does not show tables in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, navicat

I inserted table it show it success but when i find in table it doesn't show, it's happen to other table to but somehow some of the table can be selected but not show in table menu

[image]

any setting should i change to show the table name in table?

Comment: That seems a problem with your GUI tool - which one is that? Or maybe your query runs against a different database, not the one that is visible in the screen shot. Oh, and you you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: i alrady updated the navicat it's worked, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common issue with navicat. It is unlikely to be a postgres issue.

I suggest the following:

- Check that you haven't typed anything in the left pane. Often you go into search mode. Look at the bottom left and see if you see search text there. Remove it.
- You might need to reconnect to the database, or even restart navicat. Right click the database then click "Close Database", then reopen.
- You can try to upgrade navicat.

Comment: where is the left pane at, i haven't see search text, i already reconnect and it still does't show the table, right now i try to update navicat first to see if thats the problem

Comment: i update navicat and it's worked thank you

Comment: @RomliEko That is great to hear. The left pane is the one you circled in red. If you select anything there, then just start typing text will appear at the bottom in the pane, and the "objects" visible on the left will get filtered based on what you type. Often this is confusing if you don't know about it, because things just disappear if you type something there accidentally.